# After adding some firebase library in flutter android app crashing

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

After adding some firebase library in flutter android app crashing

```
 minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28


 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }


 cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2  
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5
  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1
```

> 2019-05-08 12:41:40.484 16013-16013/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: myapp.com.myapp, PID: 16013
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
>           at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.instantiate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:78)
>           at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discover(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:71)
>           at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:468)
>           at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:354)
>           at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:321)
>           at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:305)
>           at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:53)
>           at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
>           at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
>           at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:47)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6263)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5829)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5737)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   2019-05-08 12:41:40.488 16013-16013/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/base.apk", zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>             ... 24 more
>         Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:100)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:74)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:157)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>           at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
>   2019-05-08 12:41:40.491 16013-16013/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:693)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:727)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:954)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2270)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5654)
>                 ... 8 more
>         Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location
>   /data/app/myapp.com.myapp-EPX9OHQHpG7_cpLXw2wCXQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:100)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:74)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:157)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>           at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:693)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:727)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:954)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2270)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5654)
>                 ... 8 more

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Comment: yes and but one more problem  can you help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039548/androidx-localbroadcastmanagerlocalbroadcastmanager-has-different-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
firebase_core: ^0.2.5
```

to the following:

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0
```

Check here for latest changes:

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core#-changelog-tab-